# Facebook Api issue

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have generated one Facebook auth token using Facebook app. It was working fine, user was able to post on Facebook using it. But now when user posting using this token API returns success message but post is not visible on Facebook. So I have created new token using different app and posted , now this post is visible on Facebook. Question is why in both cases 
API returning success message and is there any limitation on posting from one app/token?

Comment: have same problem, tried it with another facebook account and it worked. i don't know why..